# Expand search bar on other side?

Tags: css

I have this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/064rmfat/ . What i want is when user hover on search to expand search bar but on left side. Any suggestion?

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="container-2">
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
        <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse your float

```
.container-2 input#search {
    float: right 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/064rmfat/1/